# <a> tag link will not work in firefox, but will work in IE

Tags: html

listed below is my code, this is working fine in IE but not in firefox or any other browser, can anyone see the issue? This code is generated using a .ascx header file in my asp.net application - viewing the source on IE and firefox returns the same exact thing, but when I click the item in firefox, nothing happens - when in IE, it directs me to the right page. None of the links listed below work in firefox but they all work in IE

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="19">
                <tr>
                    <a href="../homepage.aspx">
                        <td id="myHeader_td0_a" class="Tab_White" width="61" align="center" valign="middle">Home</td>

                    </a>
                    <td width="3"></td>

                        <a href="../listing/summarytreemain.aspx">
                    <td id="myHeader_td1_a" class="Tab_Blue" width="61" align="center" valign="middle" lock="true">Plan</td>

                    </a>
                    <td width="3"></td>
                    <a href="../Execution/ToDoList.aspx">
                        <td id="myHeader_td2_a" class="Tab_White" width="61" align="center" valign="middle">Execute</td>

                    </a>
                    <td width="3"></td>
                    <a href="../reports/Reports.aspx">
                        <td id="myHeader_td3_a" class="Tab_White" width="61" align="center" valign="middle">Report</td>

                    </a>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Thank you.

Comment: @JKirchartz - <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your A tag is being created before the td. This is invalid HTML and will cause unexpected behaviour.

```
<a href="../homepage.aspx">
    <td id="myHeader_td0_a" class="Tab_White" width="61" align="center" valign="middle">Home</td>
</a>
```

Needs to be

```
<td id="myHeader_td0_a" class="Tab_White" width="61" align="center" valign="middle">
     <a href="../homepage.aspx">Home</a>
</td>
```

Whatever code is generating this needs to output the HTML correctly.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<td id="myHeader_td1_a" class="Tab_Blue" width="61" align="center" valign="middle" lock="true"> 
     <a href="../listing/summarytreemain.aspx">Plan</a>
</td>
```

assuming this is actually in a table.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have incorrect html, a `td` can only be in a table. that is why you are seeing inconsistencies.

Remove the table cell and simply go with this

```
<a href="../listing/summarytreemain.aspx">
<span id="myHeader_td1_a" class="Tab_Blue" width="61" align="center" valign="middle" lock="true">Plan</span>
</a>
```

Comment: sorry, edited first post, the whole thing is inside a table - let me know if this helps

Comment: this works, but throws off some formatting - will keep as an option. thank you.